# Unable to get clientId from GoogleOAuthProvider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, google-authentication

I tried to get clientId using GoogleOAuthProvider but each and every time the popup is coming like a blank page. The url is contain clientId=undefined. And on console it showing  - [GSI_LOGGER]: The given client ID is not found. I tried to solve it but faield any idea about it..
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you register your next js project in the Google devoloper console?

Answer (score 0):

Hey bro you put the clientId key in the `.env` right?

Try just pasting the key in directly in the component.. Ive done this project and it works..

Like this...

```
 <GoogleOAuthProvider
    clientId='1050909847905-r7l6f....hasds
```

OR... if you still wanted to hide the clientId key, you can make a new seperate component just for the GoogleOAuth, and put the name of the component in `.gitignore`..

```
const GoogleProvider = (props) => {
  return (
    <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId='Your key..'>
      {props.children}  ----> Your App
    </GoogleOAuthProvider>
  );
};
```

[extracompoents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZudg.jpg)